# How best to search for the string "%00" in a variable?

Tags: string, perl

I have a Perl variable that contains (linke ther termninal calles) the string "&00".
It's possible that the string is present multiple times in the larger string.

How can I discover if the larger string contains the smaller string, to "chop" it? It's always present at the end of the string.

Something like:

```
if ($string =~ (m//))
```

Comment: &00 or %00? title doesn't match body of question.  what do you want to do if it is present multiple times?

Comment: "linke ther termninal calles" -- what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want to check or replace just the end of the string,

```
if ($string =~ /\&00$/)
```

to detect it.

Or if you just want to replace it,

```
$string =~ s/(.*)\&00$/$1/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove it if it is at the end:

```
if ( substr($string, -3) eq '&00' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [index function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sometext = "my text here contains &00 and some more text";
my $text_to_search = "&00";
print index($sometext, $text_to_search), "\n";
```

You can later use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) to chop it off.

```
my $idx = index($sometext, $text_to_search);
print substr($sometext, 0, $idx); # if it's to the end, you can alter to suit.
```